# Вызов функции из динамической .so библиотеки Linux (нет .h файла)

Tags: linux, библиотека, so

Имеется такой вопрос.
Есть библиотка .so, но нет .h файла с описанием всех функций. 
Входные /выходные значения и имя основной функции, которая мне нужна известны. 
Вопрос как вызвать эту функцию из любого другого языка программирования?

Comment: По абсолютному пути. А вопрос  хороший, я гашенный и поэтому ставлю плюс

Comment: Посмотри в сторону Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Звучит общё - "из любого другого языка программирования". Ответа на этот вопрос у меня точно нет.

В конкретном языке есть свои средства, как и в самом C++. Когда-то грузил сишную dll в Delphi, там подход в общем-то такой же, как и в сях: загрузка библиотеки по абс. пути, получение адреса функции.

Пример кода на C я тебе присылал - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031431/getprocaddress-function-in-c

Если ты знаешь сигнатуру нужной тебе функции, то далее вопрос синтаксиса языка и средств платформы. Однако внутренняя логика в самой библиотеке может препятствовать спонтанному вызову какой-то функции, ну, то есть, может вернуть пустые данные или ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

> Входные /выходные значения и имя основной функции, которая мне нужна известны.

Дык, просто объяви её тогда в соответствии с соглашением о именах/аргументах своего языка/языка библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Напиши `.h` файл сам если пишешь на си. Просто опиши структуры и объяви функцию. Потом укажи линковщику путь к библиотеке : например `-luv` для libuv в $LD_PATH.

В питоне `from ctypes import cdll` и [так далее.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html)